# Access array based on number of named key

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

```
json_data = {"fruits": ["apple", "banana", "orange"],"vegetables":["tomatoe", "cucumber", "potato"]}
```

How do I access my array numerically without having to include a numeric key?

ex:

```
json_data[0][0] #result should equal "apple"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The outer container is an unordered dictionary, not a list, so an index of 0 is meaningless. If you have some way of ordering the keys, you could then use the dict.keys() function to build a list and index that. The problem is, that keys() can come up in any order, so you'd still need some other ordering principle.

Comment: can you show an example? because i've tried this a few times just now, and `dict.keys()` always seems to come out in the right order... nevermind i got it to screw up. thanx

Comment: @TehTris - It didn't on my machine. `json_data.keys() --> ['vegetables', 'fruits']`, and that's with only 2 entries where we had a 50/50 chance of being right. dict keys are a hash table so their order will change as items are added / removed. There is collections.ordereddict which might help. But if this really is json data, its unordered to start with, so there isn't a lot you can do.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_data[list(json_data.keys())[0]][0]
```

this is how to do it, but it is extremely wrong, ugly and unpythonic, and you should probably be looking for another way to do this.

starting from the inside `json_data.keys()` returns all the keys

`list()` turns those keys into a list `[0]` after it, accesses the zeroth item in the list

`json_data[]` around that accesses the list by key

`[0]` after it accesses the zeroth item in the returned list

Also it is not guaranteed to work 100% of the time, because json_data.keys() is not guaranteed to always output at the same order.

Comment: The dict is unordered both in json and in python. There is no guarantee that you'd get the same entry twice, especially if different mixes of keys are envolved.

Comment: Your json_data.keys() is unordered.

Comment: Agreed. It just so happens to work for his dictionary of lists, but not for all instances of this same thing.